# Need modify this powershell code to use get-process

Tags: powershell

printf("%d\n", 42);  /*This powershell script needs to use the get-process in order to read a   value from a Splunk log, and return a value of 0 if successful or 1 if not. I need to use get-process, echo back the return value, and exit gracefully. The need to use get-process is what I was told to do. I'm learning powershell, would anyone share this knowledge? Here is what I'm starting with... */

```
$servers = "splunk"  
     {  
        $status = (get-process -Name<String[running]> ).Status  
        if ($status -eq "Running") {  
            "running!"  
        } else {  
            "down"  
        }
```

'

Comment: You need to run the Get-Process command on a remote PC, see if a particular process is running, then return either running or down?

Comment: Yes, that is the purpose for the script, thank you FoxDeploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not Tested.

```
$status = (Get-Process -Name ProcessName -ComputerName Server01) 
    if ($status -eq "") {  
        "down"  
    } else {  
        "Running"  
    }
```

`

Comment: Thanks Jamie. So here is my last question around your answer, is this all I need, start to finish? Is there any command block to start it? I'm struggling to learn, if you could help me with that, that's awesome. Thank you! Going to put it in. I have to test it remotely.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean?

Maybe explain exactly what you need to do.

Comment: Then please disregard. I was looking to see if it needed a #! as in a script for Bash, however I will soon find out how to call it anyways. Thanks for responding!

Comment: I use powershell ISE and just open my scripts in there.
Check out https://www.lynda.com/PowerShell-tutorials/Up-Running-PowerShell-Integrated-Scripting-Environment/376983-2.html